# ADR beat countdown in Pro Tools LE 8

Tags: pro-tools, workflow, adr

Doing some adr but still working my way around pro tools.

I've worked out how to do a 'pre roll' but I would like to add a 3 - 2 - 1 metronome just before the actor's cue to say their line to the picture.

Does anyone know how to get this feature working with the bare basic Pro Tools?

Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you all! This has really helped and led to a smooth DIY ADR session :)

Answer (score 3):

use the signal generator plug-in to create a one frame tone pop, duplicate it twice and place each one at 1/2/3 second intervals prior to the start of the line you are replacing...preferrably on a different track as well. **note, your insertion point (recording start) should actually start at the "1" count.** better to record silence than miss a syllable if the actor jumps the gun...that take might end up being useful. to make life easy for yourself afterwards (for recording lines in different locations), turn those three clips (plus the remaining frames between your "1" count and dialogue start) into a region group. then you can move the whole sequence around easily, matching the end of the group to the start of the next line you need to record.

Comment: I use Quick Punch when I do ADR for that exact reason (not missing anything) :)

Comment: You can also not open signal generator. just select 1 frame in your timeline, hit control-shift-option-3. But yeah, what Shaun said.

Comment: I have two versions of it, three beeps 1k-1k-1k and three beeps 1k-2k-1k. I have found that people tend to prefer the second one, where the second beep has a higher pitch. Is there any counter-indication to doing this?

Comment: If you have access to some bibliography, in the book (Pro tools for video and Multimedia, Second edition. Pag 136) you will find a detailed way to create and work with Countdown Beeps in Pro Tools.
Although you would think that Shaun wrote the book :)
It also sugests to work in grid mode and in loop record mode, so you can do a few takes in one go and then place them exactly where they were recorded when you drag them from the regions list. 

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Eric's comment on Shaun's answer, use loop record to do multiple takes in one go. But be sure to give the talent heads up first. :)  When loop recording I like to have "Automatically Create New Playlists When Loop Recording" checked in the Preferences > Operation pane. Makes it super easy to cut together fragments of multiple takes.

Comment: especially if you replace the exploding automation lanes with playlists...super fast auditioning and comping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the metronome in an aux track to record 3 clicks in a separate audio track. This region thus created can be given as a cue to your artist/talent to dub his lines. And punch in after the clicks to record his lines.

In India we do ADR most of the time but differently. Adr could be for films and even content localisation-translating and dubbing NGC, Discovery, Disney, etc. channels in numerous local languages and Indian content into English for international audiences.

We don't use beeps or tones. Our artists/talents just mark their lines according to previous character's guide track or video timecode on screen. Even if they miss the opening syllable, they continue their lines with the same speed till the end of the line. Since they start about 2-3 frames late, they finish late too. Then we just nudge the region left by the same no. of frames and achieve synch. If not, the talent is requested to speak slower or faster and pause on certain words to match the guide track.

Answer (score 0):

I should suggest a software called Streamers

http://figure53.com/streamers/

We use it for ADR and Foley. Cheap and awesome